# Why is my tidyverse coming up with an error message of loadNmespace etc?

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I was knitting together my R markdown to load a set of plots successfully. I decided to add these lines of code to have a word count:

```
devtools::install_github("benmarwick/wordcountaddin", type = "source", dependencies = TRUE)

wordcountaddin:::text_stats_fn_(text)
```

All of a sudden things are not knitting:

Where I am at now is tidyverse is not loading when doing `library(tidyverse)` I am getting the error message in my r markdown and my script:

```
>Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘fs’
```

I have tried everything from reinstalling the package and removing it. Restarting R. PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the `fs` package?

Comment: A missing dependency? Fix it.(Not specific to tidyverse or rmarkdown)

Comment: @divibisan thank you, i had no idea what fs was, but your suggestion worked. I have never downloaded it but this worked. THANK YOU!!

Comment: @SophiaBobrowsky Happy to help. `fs` is a dependency of tidyverse, so it would have been downloaded automatically when you installed it. I'm not sure why, but somehow when you installed the other package it must have messed up `fs` (maybe it tried to download a different version of it, and the installation failed).